# Jeditable jQuery - Add data attribute to input after init

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm using jeditable with jquery and want to add an attribute to the input after editable have been initialized. Doesn't jeditable contain any function that provides this possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.yourDivWrapper').on('focus', '.yourJEditElement input', function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.attr('name', 'value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some hacking into the js file for your jeditable. 
Then, you can add customized input with attribute just like this one:

```
$.editable.addInputType("customInput" , {
        element : function(settings, original) {
            var input = $('<input class="customClass"/>');
            if (settings.width != 'none') {
                input.width(settings.width);
            }
            if (settings.height != 'none') {
                input.height(settings.height);
            }

            input.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
            input.attr('customAttr', 'attr');
            $(this).append(input);
            return (input);
        }
    });
```

Further, if you want to add the attribute upon submission do something like:

```
$.editable.addInputType("dfsInputNumbers" , {
        element : function(settings, original) {
            var input = $('<input >');
            if (settings.width != 'none') {
                input.width(settings.width);
            }
            if (settings.height != 'none') {
                input.height(settings.height);
            }

            input.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
            $(this).append(input);
            return (input);
        },
    submit : function(settings, original) {
        $('input', this).attr("customAttr", "attr") {
    }
    });
```

I haven't tested that one yet but I have been hacking and adding some input types. Check out the tutorials : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html